# Merging strings of people's names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, merge

I have two datasets that I want to merge based off the persons name. One data set `player_nationalities` has their full name:

```
Player, Nationality
Kylian Mbappé, France
Wissam Ben Yedder, France
Gianluigi Donnarumma, Italy
```

The other dataset `player_ratings` shortens their first names with a full stop and keeps the other name(s).

```
Player, Rating
K. Mbappé, 93
W. Ben Yedder, 89
G. Donnarumma, 91
```

How do I merge these tables based on the column Player and avoid merging people with the same last name? This is my attempt:

```
df = pd.merge(player_nationality, player_ratings, on='Player', how='left')

Player, Nationality, Rating
K. Mbappé, France, NaN
W. Ben Yedder, France, NaN
G. Donnarumma, Italy, NaN
```

Comment: You have wrong/incomplete input data - you can't do safe merge and avoid errors as you have one dataset with Name Example another with N Example(who's full name is Nemo Example) and there is no way you can know this and avoid them to be wrongly merged by surname if you don't have some common column with id or something to rely on.

Comment: @Drako is it not possible to merge based off strings containing similar characters?

Comment: I downvoted question because it is not about merging but about getting usable input data - if you have bad/corrupted data - its difficult to do something useful - instead of suffering with error prone solution I suggest to try to get proper input data

Comment: of course it is possible to merge - but question was - how to merge avoiding errors - that's not possible as I already showed in example in previous code: player1: Name Example player 2: Nemo Example - those will always be wrongly merged as 1 player because in second data set they both are represented as N. Example - you can't do anything reliable with bad input data!

Comment: Apologies @Drako, thanks for the feedback! I need to get better at titling my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to normalize the keys in both DataFrames in order to merge them.
One idea would be to create a function to process the full name in `player_nationalities` and merge on the processed value for player name. eg:

```
def convert_player_name(name):
    try:
        first_name, last_name = name.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
        return f'{first_name[0]}. {last_name}'
    except ValueError:
        return name

    

player_nationalities['processed_name'] = [convert_player_name(name) for name in player_nationalities['Player']]
df_merged = player_nationalities.merge(player_ratings, left_on='processed_name', right_on='Player')
```

[out]

```
               Player_x Nationality processed_name       Player_y  Rating
0         Kylian Mbappé      France      K. Mbappé      K. Mbappé      93
1     Wissam Ben Yedder      France  W. Ben Yedder  W. Ben Yedder      89
2  Gianluigi Donnarumma       Italy  G. Donnarumma  G. Donnarumma      91
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! Unfortunately this returns me with a ValueError: `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. Do you have any idea where this is coming from? Could potentially be the issue with players having two last names (i.e. Wissam Ben Yedder / W. Ben Yedder)

Comment: It's more likely names with no spaces. Try `player_nationalities[player_nationalities['Player'].str.count(' ').eq(0)]` ..? Any Players?

Comment: You're correct, players with single names showing up (e.g. 'Marquinhos, 'Emerson').

Comment: Try changing the first line of the processing function to `first_name, *last_name = name.split(' ', maxsplit=1)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, produces a new NameError: `name 'first_name' is not defined`. This is a tricky one!

Comment: Maybe just need to handle it with in a try/except block, I'lll update the answer

Comment: That works great, thanks Chris! Enjoyed going through the process with an experienced coder, very insightful.